# Helm - select with Tab instead of Enter?

Tags: helm

In Visual Studio and Intellij I can press Tab to select the highlighted auto-completion.

In Helm: Is there a way to give Tab the same behavior as Return?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I could not find any resource on this. Only "How do I use Tab for autocomplete" which was always answered with "you don't need Tab in Helm".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add this to your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'helm
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "TAB") #'helm-maybe-exit-minibuffer))
```

This should work in all cases except where a given helm source binds something different than `helm-maybe-exit-minibuffer` to `RET`, but off the top of my head I can't think of any sources that do.

Note that if you only want to apply this change for a specific source (rather than for all helm sources) you could see if that source has its own associated keymap, and bind it there instead.

Comment: Awesome, works fine! Thank you so much! But as a lisp noob: Why is there a hash in front of 'helm-maybe... ?

Comment: It is completely optional.  The `#'foo` is shorthand for `(function foo)`  The docstring for `function` says: `Like 'quote', but preferred for objects which are functions. In byte compilation, 'function' causes its argument to be compiled. 'quote' cannot do that.`

Answer (score 1):

I just watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k78f8NYYIto) where they show this code to accomplish what you want.

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "TAB") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```